# Rancher Stuck At Waiting For SSH to be Avilable

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, rancher

We are setting up cluster on amazon ec2 from rancher through private subnet but it hangs at "Waiting for SSH to be available"

We are able to create cluster when we use public subnet in amazon ec2.But it stuck when we use private subnet.We are able to ping the amazon instance from rancher server.

Comment: Hi @saurabh-tandel, welcome to the SO club ) For SSH, ping is not enough. Try to check 22 port: `telnet <server> 22`

Comment: Hi Saurabh.. could you put a bit more detail in your question about what you are trying to achieve - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example